# Missing required view with ID, navigation graph android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigationview, android-navigation-graph

I have 2 navigation graphs in my app
I have 2 fragments with same name but different UI and resides in different package as well.

Now I navigate to one fragment it works and while I navigate to other I get the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.octave.staging:id/cashPieChart
    at com.octave.more.databinding.CashDistributionFragmentBinding.bind(CashDistributionFragmentBinding.java:104)
    at com.octave.more.databinding.CashDistributionFragmentBinding.inflate(CashDistributionFragmentBinding.java:65)
    at com.octave.more.cash.CashDistributionFragment.onCreateView(CashDistributionFragment.kt:34)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
```

These are my nav graphs

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dashboard_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="dashboard_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/dashboard_fragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_equityFragment"
        app:destination="@id/dashboardCashDistributionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_dashboardFragment_to_cashDistributionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/dashboardEquityFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardEquityFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.dashboard.equity.EquityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/equity_fragment"
    android:label="EquityFragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dashboardCashDistributionFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.dashboard.cash.CashDistributionFragment"
    android:label="cash_distribution_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/cash_distribution_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

the second graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/more_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/moreFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/moreFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.more.MoreFragment"
    android:label="more_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/more_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_moreFragment_to_equityFragment"
        app:destination="@id/equityFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_moreFragment_to_cashDistributionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/cashDistributionFragment" />
   
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/equityFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.more.equity.EquityFragment"
    android:label="equity_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/equity_fragment" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cashDistributionFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.more.cash.CashDistributionFragment"
    android:label="cash_distribution_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/cash_distribution_fragment" />

 </navigation>
```

And the the navigation code is as

```
findNavController().navigate(DashboardFragmentDirections.actionDashboardFragmentToEquityFragment())

findNavController().navigate(MoreFragmentDirections.actionMoreFragmentToCashDistributionFragment())
```

Both have different action id's as well as location as well.
Can't seem to figure out the issue

Comment: Are you using the deprecated `<fragment>` tag in your activity XML? You should **always** use `FragmentContainerView`.

Comment: i have added code for navigation graph xml's not the layout xml's. What you are saying is correct for layout xml's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project is on multi module approach
Issue was due to view binding as both the layout xml's also had the same name and resides in 2 different module.

After changing the name of 1 xml it is working.

However what I don't get is same file names exists in different packages and yet view binding referenced it to first one.